# Disable Push State in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, firebug, pushstate

I've run into a bug in IE8 (emulating IE7) that is causing my iFrame push-state hack to redirect to the URL in the iFrame and I'm having a heck-of-a-time trying to debug in IE.  If there a wya to disable Firefox's recognition of push-state so I can replicate the situation in Firefox (or even Chrome) but still have the use of the console window for more effective debugging?

Another option is if anyone has seen this where the iFrame push-state hack will work correctly and then redirect to the iFrame's url (loosing the forward capability which is what leads me to believe it's redirecting)

Another note: there are no window.location =  or document.location lines that would obviously cause the redirect, that was the 2nd thing I looked at once I saw the forward button was disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can disable pushState in Firefox, the setting is called `browser.history.allowPushState`

1. Open »about:config« page in Firefox
2. Search for »pushstate«
3. doubleclick the `browser.history.allowPushState` setting